# CLI create super user in Django with raw python, no python shell

Tags: django, ansible

As part of an automation process I need to create the superuser for Django via python in the CLI.

I could consider other possibilities to this problem but only if they're easily scritable with ansible.

Anyway, this is what I have so far (for Django 1.6)

```
python -c "import os; 
  os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_proj.live_settings'); 
  from django.conf import settings;"

python -c "from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model; 
  user_model = get_user_model();
  user_model.objects.db_manager().create_superuser('admin', 'admin@admin.com', 'ad_pass')"
```

However, when I run this i get this error.

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Any idea what's wrong or how to fix it please? It seems strange it should complain about DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE when it has been explicitly set..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're seeing is because you're running it as two separate python commands.  You import the settings in the first, then python exits, then you start the second (which hasn't imported settings).

If you put them all into one `python -c` call, it should work.

It also looks like you're not passing the right number of arguments to .db_manager().  See this for more details:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/multi-db/#using-managers-with-multiple-databases

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a custom manage.py command?

[appname]/managment/commands/add_user.py:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from optparse import make_option

class Command(BaseCommand):
    option_list = BaseCommand.option_list + (
        make_option('--user',
            action='store',
            default=None,
            help='Username for new user'),
        make_option('--password',
            action='store',
            default=None,
            help='User Password'),
        make_option('--email',
            action='store',
            default=None,
            help='User Email Address'),
        )

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username = kwargs.get('user'),
            password = kwargs.get('password'),
            email = kwargs.get('email')
            )
        user.save( )
```

add a user with the following command from the CLI:

```
python manage.py add_user --user=tester --password=tester --email=tester@test.org
```

Answer (score 1):

With the code that [shtuff.it](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1183790/shtuff-it) specified, work successfully and create the user but I cannot login to the created user, so I need to modify the code to create the superuser.

P.S: I have changed the order of parameter, like I have put the email before the password and it work for me.

Here is the complete code that we can use to create the django superuser from CLI:

[appname]/managment/commands/add_user.py:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from optparse import make_option

class Command(BaseCommand):
    option_list = BaseCommand.option_list + (
        make_option('--user',
            action='store',
            default=None,
            help='Username for new user'),
        make_option('--password',
            action='store',
            default=None,
            help='User Password'),
        make_option('--email',
            action='store',
            default=None,
            help='User Email Address'),
        )

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = User.objects.create_superuser(
            username = kwargs.get('user'),
            email = kwargs.get('email'),
            password = kwargs.get('password').strip(),
            )
        user.save( )
```

Then use the following command to add the user from CLI:

```
python manage.py add_user --user=USERNAME --password=PASSWORD --email=mail@test.com
```

Comment: THis is all pretty much moot now that there is an excellent Django module for Ansible - http://docs.ansible.com/django_manage_module.html

Comment: [rix](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1004781/rix), but with that module, you cannot create the superuser, if it is possible, please let us know with example. Thanks

Comment: You can use it to run any manage.py commands although admittedly not createsuperuser.  However, in this instance, it would make much more sense to create a fixture which would contain your superuser details and password hash.  Use ansible to install the fixture and you have you superuser without having your to define your actual password in version control and also without having to create a custom management command.

Answer (score 1):

For my needs I have created little app that creates superuser by using fixtures or migrations. 
https://github.com/inirudebwoy/django-mksuperuser